# How do i call a method outside a class with the same object

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Classe FoodManagerPane that is extended by BorderPane. In this class I build my pane from different class components. For example, I have a class MenuBar, which I initialize in this FoodManagerPane and insert into the pane.

**FoodManagerPane extends BorderPane**

```
public class FoodManagerPane extends BorderPane {
     private MenuBarView menuBarView = new MenuBarView();
     private Button buttonDelete = null;
     ...

     private Button getButtonDelete() {
      if (buttonDelete == null) {
        buttonDelete = new Button("Delete");
        buttonDelete.setOnAction(deleteEvent);
      }
     return buttonDelete;
     }

     public void refreshData() {
     this.getFoodTableView().setItems(DataHandler.INSTANCE.foodlist());
     }
}
```

*DataHandler.INSTANCE.foodlist()* returns the current entries of the list

In this class I have among other things the method *refreshData()*, which synchronizes my data from the ObservableList with the view.

I also create a button to remove objects from my list. The ActionEvent for this I defined in a separate class.

**ActionEvent for DeleteButton**

```
public class DeleteFoodEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

private final FoodTableView foodTableView = new FoodTableView();

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    //do something

    foodTableView.setItems(DataHandler.INSTANCE.foodlist());
    }
}

}
```

So in my ActionEvent class I defined that the element should be removed from the list (that works) but then I want to update the table directly, which unfortunately is not working here.

If I define the ActionHandler directly in the FoodManagerPane and call the method *refreshData()* here it works. But I would like to outsource the event. Does anyone here have an idea?

**UPDATE:**
**DataHandler-Class**

```
public enum DataHandler {

INSTANCE;

private boolean update;

private List<Food> foodlist = null;

DataHandler() {
    getFoodlist();
}

public ObservableList<Food> foodlist() {
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(getFoodlist());
}

private List<Food> getFoodlist() {
    if (foodlist == null) {
        foodlist = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    System.out.println("The List: " + foodlist);
    return foodlist;
}

public void createFood(Food food) {
    System.out.println("createFood()");
    this.foodlist.add(food);
    update = true;
}

public void deleteFood(Food food) {
    System.out.println("deleteFood()");
    this.foodlist.remove(food);
    update = true;
}

public void deleteFoodlist(List<Food> foodlist) {
    System.out.println("deleteFoodlist()");
    for (Food food : foodlist) {
        deleteFood(food);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add `DataHandler` class/enum too?

Comment: Added to my post

Comment: You can't use `FoodTableView foodTableView = new FoodTableView();` and expect it to work, since `footTableView` is not the same table view in which the items are being displayed.  You need to do `new DeleteFoodEventHandler(tableView)` and use the same object.

Comment: @kendavidson You're right, i didn't saw that problem. It Works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution if someone has a similar problem. Many thanks to **@kendavidson**

```
public class AddFoodEventHandler {

public void addFood(TableView tableView) {
    
    try {
        //do something
        } else {
            // do more
            // refresh the tableView
            tableView.setItems(DataHandler.INSTANCE.foodlist());
        }
    } 
}

}
```